# How to read data from a component with multiple ports

Tags: python, redhawksdr

I am trying to read data from a compent from a python script being new to redhawk and flowing some examples I have the following but it expects only one port

```
from ossie.utils import redhawk, sb
dom = redhawk.attach("REDHAWK_DEV")
app=dom.apps[0]
print(app)
comp = app.comp[0]
output_data = sb.DataSink()
comp.connect(output_data)
```

Which errors with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/redhawk/core/lib/python/ossie/utils/model/__init__.py", line 327, in connect
    raise RuntimeError, ret_str
RuntimeError: Multiple ports matched interfaces on connect, must specify providesPortName or usesPortName
Possible matches:
  Interface: IDL:BULKIO/dataShort:1.0, component/port:  rh.basic_components_demo_230_071003375_1/SigGen_sine/dataShort_out     __localDataSink_1/shortIn
  Interface: IDL:BULKIO/dataFloat:1.0, component/port:  rh.basic_components_demo_230_071003375_1/SigGen_sine/dataFloat_out     __localDataSink_1/floatIn
```

The component is the rh.SigGen Component from the basic waveform example project.

How do you read from the sink and output the floats?
I thinking something like

```
...
comp.connect(output_data)
while (data=comp.read()) :
   print("Value : "+data)
```

Comment: in a python session you can use help(comp.connect) and it will provide the API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

your error can be solved with something like:

```
comp.connect(output_data, usesPortName="dataFloat_out")
```

in order to print float samples, you can implement a REDHAWK Component to do that... you can also plot data using:

```
sb.IDELocation("/path/to/ide/eclipse/directory")
plot=sb.Plot()
comp.connect(plot, usesPortName="dataFloat_out")
```